# DOM change color with reload

Tags: javascript

I read the book “Designing Data-Intensive Applications” chapter 2, it compare the DOM with CSS:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="selected">
    <p>Sharks</p>
    <ul>
      ....
```

```js
var liElements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
  if (liElements[i].className === "selected") {
    var children = liElements[i].childNodes;
    for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
      var child = children[j];
      if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && child.tagName === "P") {
        child.setAttribute("style", "background-color: blue");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This JavaScript imperatively sets the element Sharks to have a blue background... it also has some serious problems:

If the selected class is removed (e.g., because the user **clicks a different page**), the blue color won’t be removed, even if the code is **rerun** — and so the item will remain highlighted until the entire page is reloaded. With CSS, the browser automatically detects when the `li.selected > p` rule no longer applies and removes the blue background as soon as the selected class is removed.

Here is my question:
1. Why does the page not reload when clicks a different page?
2. What does rerun mean? Need it not reload?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, you set in attribute dom, event u remove class is not effect
because dom set have style background blue but not by css selector class

```
child.setAttribute("style", "background-color: blue");
```

if you want change color every click in list

try it

```js
 $(function(){

    $('ul li').on('click',function(){
        $('ul li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

  });
```

```css
ul li.selected{
        background: blue;
        color: #fff;
      }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
      
    </style>

    </head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="">
                <p>Sharks</p>
        </li>
        <li class="">
                <p>Sharks 2</p>
        </li>
    <ul>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  
 


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: could you answer my question directly? I can not understand you very well